# Customer address does not automatically update in order details

Tags: orders, customer, address

This is the problem:

A customer creates an order.
After that he changes his address on the customer account page.
The address on the order he already created does not automatically update.
So we send the order to the wrong address.

Anyone a solution for this?

Is there for example a possibility to get a notification by email when a customer changes his address?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an observer to the customer address save event: **customer_address_save_after**

This event will be triggered every time someone saves or creates an address.

You can add whatever functionality you need in the observer. You can send out a notification email, add a note to any open orders the customer has, etc.